# Imagick resizeImage is not applying to multi page PDF's

Tags: php, imagick

I'm converting multi page PDF's to individual images, however only the last page in the PDF is being resized and compressed (line 5 onwards):

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->setOption("pdf:use-trimbox","true");
$image->setResolution(300,300);
$image->readImage("test1.pdf");
$image->resizeImage(800,0,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(65);
$image->setImageFormat("jpeg");
$image->writeImages("name.jpeg",true);
```

I need to be able to output each PDF page as a single, resized and compressed image. If anybody could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

The images are held as separate images internally in the Imagick object. To resize them all, you should call resize on them all:

```
foreach ($image as $subImage) {
    $subImage->resizeImage(800, 0, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);
}
```